# while using subprocess in python the output is coming with new line

Tags: python, string

When i execute the below code the output is coming with new line.

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
password_string='abc_123'
cmd=["java", "-cp", "ABC.jar","com.sc.tsaas.EncryptionDecryptionAES",password_string]
i=subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print (i)
```

Output :
`aSjD9H2NfmX02KpFg==`

New line is coming in output and need your help to solve this.

Comment: There's always a newline there; the only reason you don't see it in shell is that shells strip trailing newlines from command substitution output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To strip the newline, do `i=subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].rstrip("\n")`